# PIC12F programming without wasting pins

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming

I was used to Silabs MCU, but this time I would like to use a PIC12F.

According to the datasheet I have 6 GPIOs, but I need 3 pins for programming. Is there any documentation on how to leverage these pins once the device is programmed?

[image]

Comment: Section 28.1 of the datasheet goes into some detail on this. The chip will just use the ICSP lines for GPIO unless it is commanded into ICSP mode on initial power-up by a programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically what's going to happen is that a serial pulse train is going to be applied to DAT and CLK, and a high voltage (12V?) to MCLR.

Just make sure your circuit won't load down or disrupt the programming signals. Also take care that the pulses won't cause unintended operation or damage anything.

The MCLR is additionally restricted to input only.

Besides that you can use the pins however you want. The programming function is basically transparent after the chip is running. The pins have ports and peripherals the same as any other.